# How to select only last matching result if this is equal to x from mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

i've three tables in my mysql database:

orders table (example):

```
orders
id  | user_id | price
1   | 10       | 29.99
2   | 20       | 29.99
3   | 30       | 29.99
4   | 40       | 29.99
```

users table:

```
users
id   | name   | surname
10   | mark   | white
20   | john   | long
30   | anders | red
40   | john   | smith
```

and orders_updates table

```
orders_updates
id | order_id | status_id | date
1  | 1        | 1         | 03/05/2020
2  | 1        | 2         | 04/05/2020
3  | 2        | 1         | 05/05/2020
4  | 3        | 1         | 06/05/2020
5  | 4        | 1         | 06/05/2020
6  | 4        | 2         | 06/05/2020
```

What i need:

```
new orders
order_id | user_id | name   | surname
2        | 20      | john   | long
3        | 30      | anders | red
```

Now, i need to create the "new orders" page (orders_updates.status_id = 1), how i can get only orders with only status_id=1 and not some other status_id.

This is where i'm stuck:

```
SELECT o.*, u.*
FROM orders o, users u, orders_updates ou
WHERE o.user_id = u.id
AND (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM order_updates WHERE order_updates.order_id = o.id)
AND ou.order_id = o.id
```

Thank you all.

Comment: Side note: About the way you're storing dates. If you're not too far into this, I recommend that you don't store those as plain text, you're going to have a bit of hard time querying later on. MySQL has built-in functions for this when using the same column type.

Comment: Thank you @Funky Forty Niner, what's your suggestions?

Comment: How come are you only expecting `order_id` 2 and 3. I see `order_id ` 1 and 4 also have `status_id` as 1?

Comment: Welcome @Davide In your case, you would need to alter your column to be an `DATE` type, but then you'll have to start over. You might get an error for it. If so, delete your data and then alter the column type. Go through these also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html - https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-datetime/ which could be of use.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
select
    order_id,
    user_id,
    name,
    surname

from orders_updates ou

join orders o
on ou.order_id = o.id

join users u
on u.id = o.user_id

where ou.status_id = 1

order by
    order_id
```

Answer (score -1):

I would go with:

```
select
    order_id,
    user_id,
    name,
    surname

from orders_updates ou

join orders o
on ou.order_id = o.id

join users u
on u.id = o.user_id

where ou.status_id = 1
and ou.order_id not in (  
  select distinct order_id  
  from orders_updates  
  where status_id in (2,3)  
)  

order by
    order_id
```

I put as a sample status_id in (2,3) but you should include there all the other status_ids you don’t want to be considered.

Hope that helps!

Comment: what’s the problem with my suggestion?